# Laying out music and text

Tags: lilypond, abc

I'd like too create some charts like

https://www.google.com/search?q=rudiments+chart&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1

This is basically using inline simple musical percussion like staves and text around it.

What is the best way to go about this? It should be relatively robust(even full grand staves) and not too hard to setup/use(else it might be easier to use another program than tex).

It would be like lilypond but I'd like to have inline without too much arrangement/positioning issues or having to write a lot of code simply to get something very simple. Again, if it's too much work it would be easier to use a notation program and export the graphics. I'm not too familiar with lilypond and the others to know which would be best(I have done some lilypond stuff in the past and it could work if I could get it to work inline properly(never was able to do inside latex with the environment).

Comment: Perhaps the [tag:musixtex] package would be helpful?

Comment: IF you want a multi column layout as in some of your linked pictures, I would import graphics. If you create PDFs of the notation, you don't lose any resolution. Lilypond and Lilypond-book are fine for alternating blocks of text and music down the page, but not for a more complicated layout. Alternatively, you can make that sort of layout entirely within a modern notation program like Dorico which supports text and music "frames" laid out any way you want in the page..

Answer (score 2):

In Lilypond, you can consider using a Score block `\score { }` inside a Markup block `\markup { }`, as explained here: [lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/formatting-text#music-notation-inside-markup](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/formatting-text#music-notation-inside-markup). This allows you to mix texts and scores along lines and columns.

See these more practical examples: [lsr.di.unimi.it/LSR/Item?id=701](http://lsr.di.unimi.it/LSR/Item?id=701) and [lsr.di.unimi.it/LSR/Item?id=1013](http://lsr.di.unimi.it/LSR/Item?id=1013)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `mwe.tex` to get this with LuaLaTeX:

```tex
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[pass-fonts]{lyluatex}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  1. Single Stroke Roll & \lilypond[nostaff]{
    a32[_"R" a_"L" a_"R" a]_"L"
    a32[_"R" a_"L" a_"R" a]_"L"
  }\\
  \\
  2. Single Stroke Four & \lilypond[nostaff]{
    \tuplet 3/2 {a16[_"R"_"L" a_"L"_"R" a]_"R"_"L" a8_"L"_"R"}
    \tuplet 3/2 {a16[_"R"_"L" a_"L"_"R" a]_"R"_"L" a8_"L"_"R"}
  }\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

After compiling with command `lualatex --shell-escape mwe`, here is the result:

[image]